# Defining and calling a function in a React Native component event

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following:

```
import { DraxView } from 'react-native-drax';

function MyComponent(props) {
   function test() { console.log('message') }
   const test2 = () => { console.log('message') }
   return (
     <DragView
      onDragDrop={ console.log('message')}
     >
    </DragView>
   )
}
```

This correctly logs to the console every time the event occurs. However, the message is also logged the first time `MyView` is rendered. To avoid this, have tried replacing with the following:

```
onDragDrop={ test }
```

or

```
onDragDrop={ test2 }
```

Neither of these appear to be called, as nothing is logged when the event happens.

What is correct way to define and call a function in this way?

Thanks

Comment: Are on you sure that `onEvent` is a valid prop? I don't see it anywhere in the react native docs. My guess is that `onEvent` is a custom prop and the log is only happening on mount because that's when it reads the value. Try replacing `onEvent` with `onPress` or some similar event handler from the docs. Depends on which component you use

Comment: That aside: `onEvent` expects a function. The code gives it the result of running `console.log`, which is `undefined`. It logs every time `MyComponent` is rendered. The correct way is to provide a function reference as you do in the latter snippets.

Comment: Edited the question to give the specific component <DragView> and event onDragDrop(), as well as the import. onDragDrop={ console.log('message')} logs to the console when the component is dragged, but using a function reference, e.g. onDragDrop={ test2 }, does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onDragDrop={ console.log('message')}` fires the function immediately during rendering, because expression inside the `{ }` executes right away.

All these options works:

```
function test1() { console.log('test1') }
const test2 = () => { console.log('test2') }
return <>
  <Button title="TEST1" onPress={test1}/>
  <Button title="TEST2" onPress={test2}/>
  <Button title="TEST3" onPress={() => console.log('test3')}/>
</>
```

Comment: Have marked answer as correct as your example works, although it does not work when using DragView.onDragDrop()

Comment: The solution was replacing onDragDrop with onDragStart - this works for my use case